git-filter-repo long run time : what does it need?
So I've got git-filter-repo up and running on a rather large repo, but once it starts it never seems to finish.
I've read people talking about it taking days, which fine, but I would like to make its job easier.  I can probably justify provisioning a new VM or borrowing some hardware to run the task, but I was wondering:
What specs does git-filter-repo care about?  Does it want a lot of single threaded CPU? Cores? Memory? disk speed?  Something else?

waht action(s) are you applying on your history ?

Mainly memory and single thread-CPU.
newren/git-filter-repo issue 271 "analyze is slow/stuck in big repo "
What git filter-repo does is operate on the output of:
git rev-list --topo-order --reverse --all | \
git diff-tree --stdin --always --root --format=%H%n%P%n%cd \
              --date=short -M -t -c --raw --combined-all-paths

In that thread, the main source of "slowness" was a git config setting, which impacted filter-repo:

diff.renamelimit (set to 999999 instead of the default 4096)

a large history of commits with many renames:

We have many root tree level renaming/refactoring over the years.



So first make sure your git config settings are standard, then consider the type of filter command you will make of that repository.
